# Find internet story about a dog who rescued a woman from drowning by using a leverage from wood and the leash

Tags: dogs, behavior, history

I remember reading that a dog saved a woman from drowning in a swamp or similar (in the US I think) by creating a leverage from wood and the leash. It was told in first-person from herself and I read it on Ranker.com or Reddit. Now I cannot find it again.

The event, if true, would indicate that the dog has awareness of mechanical leverage as discovered by Archimedes that the force with a leverage is greater than the original force. This might very well be possible since many dogs can jump in the air and catch something in the air which is the equivalent of the mathematical physics of calculating the trajectory of a moving object in the air.

Do you think it's possible to find the story again? I search online for some time but could not find it.

Comment: Independant of whether or not anyone finds the original story, I highly doubt that any dog truely understands mechanical principles. Any 6 year old child can catch a ball, years before being able to calculate trejactories, simply because of the experience of how balls fly. You onviously can use a computer, but I assume you don't fully understand how all of its components work. Archimedes didn't invent leverage, he researched the devices people around him used without fully understanding their underlaying physical principles. And anyone on Reddit can come up with a sensational lie.

Comment: @Elmy Animals using tools actually have 100s of reported observations ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_use_by_animals ) If we are sceptical about the story then we really are obliged to find the story and see what the claims are, instead of your straw man argument and what it means to "understand" the laws of nature instead of the sole act of using a leverage.